# how call the jquery file as globally

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to call the jquery file globally

I am working in Mean Technology

i have a UI (working Html page).  In that UI has header, footer, sidebar these,These header footer, sidebar are coming from separate UI. I have combined to use in my html.

I have sidebar, header, footer by using this div tag.

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar responsive ace-save-state" ng-controller="SlideController" ng-include="'slidebar.html'">

            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $(".sidebar ul li ul li").closest("li").find(".active").removeClass("active");
                    $("#Expense").addClass("active").parents(".nav li").addClass("active open");

                });
            </script>
```

in my side bar.html

```
  <script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

in originalUI.html (working Html page)

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

also used this jquery.
here i have used date-picker it is not working properly. it return

```
jquery-2.1.4.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't know why. can anybody tell me

Thanks

Vinoth s

Comment: if i delete in sidebar, sidebar is not working. so that only i have used twice

Comment: place jQuery in header

Comment: @GyandeepSharma header means, head tag?

Comment: you have header.php file sapate. right? that header.php you are calling on all pages. so You have to add jQuery file in header.php, and yes head section is located in header.php. And provide full path of jQuery.

Comment: already i have included in my header,footer

Comment: sir you have to add jQuery only once.. Don't need to add on every file.

Comment: if i use jquery only in header means my date picker is not working

Comment: Sir add this line in header...<script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> . Not datepicker JQuery..

Comment: sir, if i used only in header  my side bar not working.

Comment: Can you show me full HTML code ?

Comment: go to this link you view http://plnkr.co/edit/lKJB4JYgsC2TnW1EJ1At?p=catalogue

Comment: Add datepicker CSS and JS in your code...

Comment: i have already added. that is not a working plunkr

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>

    <title>PROJECT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</title>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <!-- basic scripts -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <!-- text fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fonts.googleapis.com.css" />

    <!-- ace styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace.min.css" class="ace-main-stylesheet" id="main-ace-style" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-skins.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-rtl.min.css" />
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/ace-elements.min.js"></script>
   
   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try { ace.settings.loadState('sidebar') } catch (e) { }

        // ****  Deactive Back Button ****
        var history_api = typeof history.pushState !== 'undefined';
        if (history_api) history.pushState(null, '', '#/');
    </script>


    <!--   Start  09/03/17 -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstraptable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Angular.js -->
    <script src="assets/js/AngularJS1.3.12.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/route.js"></script>
    <link href="assets/css/xeditable/xeditable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="assets/css/xeditable/xeditable.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/notify.js"></script>
    <script src="controller/Expense.js"></script>
    <script src="controller/paging.js"></script>

    <script src="controller/UserNameShow.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/Angular-Cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/angular-animate.js"></script>


    <!--Clear Search-->
    <script src="assets/js/ClearSearch.js"></script>
    <!--Healthcare styles-->
    <link href="assets/css/HealthCareCss.css" rel="stylesheet" />



    <style>
        .ui-datepicker table {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .ui-datepicker-calendar {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .panel-body {
            height: calc(100vh - 180px);
        }
        
        .modal-dialog {
            width: 400px;
        }
        
        .modal-dialogUI {
            width: 606px;
        }
        
        .scrollbar {
            overflow-y: auto;
            height: calc(100vh - 400px);
        }
        
        input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
            display: none;
        }
        
        #divLoading {
            display: none;
        }
        
        #divLoading.show {
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 100;
            background-image: url("assets/Images/LoadingPanel.gif");
            /*background-color:#666;*/
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
            opacity: 10.4;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function convertToUppercase(el) {
            if (!el || !el.value) return;
            el.value = el.value.toUpperCase();
        }
        //datepicker With only Month and Year   -- Start
        $(function () {
            debugger
            $('#ExpenseMonth').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                viewMode: "months", 
                 minViewMode: 1,
      format: 'mm/yyyy',
                onClose: function () {
                    var Month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var Year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(Year, Month, 1));
                },

                beforeShow: function () {
                    if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                        Year = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
                        Month = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                        $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(Year, Month, 1));
                        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(Year, Month, 1));
                    }
                }
            });
        });
                //datepicker With only Month and Year   -- Start
    </script>




    <!--   End  09/03/17 -->



</head>

<body class="no-skin clearPadding">
            <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar responsive ace-save-state" ng-controller="SlideController" ng-include="'slidebar.html'">

            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $(".sidebar ul li ul li").closest("li").find(".active").removeClass("active");
                    $("#Expense").addClass("active").parents(".nav li").addClass("active open");

                });
            </script>


        </div>
  <label for="ExpenseMonth">Month :</label>
                                        <input name="ExpenseMonth" id="ExpenseMonth" class="date-picker" /> 

</body>

</html>
```

Datepicker is working in this code.

Comment: for me, need only month and year.  when the mouse is clicked into anywhere the selected month and year only shown in text box

Comment: and i want to show only the month and year date are all no need

Comment: i have mentioned above.  i want to show only the month and year. date are all no need

Comment: Sir Code is exactly what you want. months and year.. Please check my answer;;

Comment: see the text box it return date also. and i need month name like may not 05

Comment: Done... Check Again